# Why does the terminal not hold my root password for sudo?

Tags: command-line, password, sudo, git

I stopped using Ubuntu for a while (since 12.10) and recently came back to it.
From what I remember, it used to only ask for the root password once for a terminal session (for sudo commands). Now it asks me everytime I want to sudo something. Is there a way to fix this? or is this intentional?

The same thing happens with git. I have enter my credentials everytime I want to commit. I know my friends on on mac don't need to do this. Are the two issues related?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sudo`, by default, times out after a certain number of minutes, 15 by default.  You can change this by running:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then, at the bottom, add:

```
Defaults:userName timestamp_timeout=timeoutInMinutes
```

Where `userName` is your username and `timeoutInMinutes` is the timeout (in minutes) you would like. To always ask for a password, use `0`, to only ask once per sessions use `-1`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit.

For git you will need to configure it to remember your username and password. See this Stack Overflow question for more information: [How to make Git only ask password when push to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672787/how-to-make-git-only-ask-password-when-push-to-remote-repository).

Also, your `sudo` password is *not* the root password. The root password is the password for the account `root` (which is disabled by default in Ubuntu). `sudo` just uses *your* user's password. A subtle difference, but it is there.